# Apache Flink: Unable to convert the Table object to DataSet object

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am using the Table API on Flink 1.4.0. I have some `Table` objects to be convert to a `DataSet` of type `Row`. The project was built using Maven and imported on IntelliJ. I have the following code and the IDE cannot resolve the method `tableenv.toDataSet()` method. Please help me out. Thank you.

```
ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
BatchTableEnvironment tableEnvironment = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);
...
tableEnvironment.registerTableSource("table1",csvSource);
Table table1 = tableEnvironment.scan("table1");
DataSet<Row> result = tableEnvironment.toDataSet(table1, Row.class);
```

The last statement causes an error

> "Cannot resolve toDataSet() method"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not import the right `BatchTableEnvironment`.

Please check that you import `org.apache.flink.table.api.java.BatchTableEnvironment` instead of `org.apache.flink.table.api.BatchTableEnvironment`. The former is the common base class for the Java and Scala variants.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a `DataSet` from a `csv` file, do it like following:

`DataSet<YourType> csvInput = env.readCsvFile("hdfs:///the/CSV/file") ...`

More on this: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/batch/#data-sources